# How to disable the first suggestions in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable the first suggestion? when I press tab, it just finishes the word only, different from the second one

[image]

I want the first suggestion is deleted, and the second becomes the first suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first suggestion is **keyword** (text) suggestion.

The second is a **snippet** suggestion.

You can change the setting: **`editor.snippetSuggestions`** (**Editor: Snippet Suggestion** in GUI) and set its value to **`top`**

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
```

Or change the setting: **`editor.suggest.showWords`**

```
"editor.suggest.showWords": false
```

There are many other `suggest` settings, use the Settings GUI to search for it.